# why no image is displayed on histogram equalization : python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

```
 import numpy as np
 import cv2
 import scipy.misc, math
 from scipy.misc.pilutil import Image

while True:
  img = Image.open('img.jpg').convert(L)
  img1 = scipy.misc.fromimage(img)
  f1 = img1.flatten()
  hist,bins = np.histogram(img1, 256,[0,255])
  cdf = hist.cumsum
  cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
  cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
  cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0)
  im2 = cdf[f1]
  im3 = np.reshape(im2,img1.shape)
  im4 = scipy.misc.toimage(img3)
  im4.show()
```

I am trying to histogram equalize an image. When i run the program, neither an output image is displayed nor an error is shown.

Can anyone tell me where am going wrong

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PIL well enough to answer your question, but it may be helpful if you mention the version of PIL on your sstem. What does `python -c "import PIL;print(PIL.VERSION);print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)"` print? Paste the output into your question so people don't have to rummage through the comments to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy.misc, math
from scipy.misc.pilutil import Image

while True:
  img = Image.open('img.jpg').convert(L)
  img1 = scipy.misc.fromimage(img)
  f1 = img1.flatten()
  hist,bins = np.histogram(img1, 256,[0,255])
  cdf = hist.cumsum
  cdf_m = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
  cdf_m = (cdf_m - cdf_m.min())*255/(cdf_m.max()-cdf_m.min())
  cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_m,0)
  im2 = cdf[f1]
  im3 = np.reshape(im2,img1.shape)
  im4 = scipy.misc.toimage(im3)
  im4.format = "PNG" # out of paranoia mainly
  im4.show()
```

Comment: Did you also change scipy.misc.toimage(img3) to scipy.misc.toimage(im3)?

Comment: yes...it was a typoerror in this space. Any other solution why its nt workin